# Check if a varchar column can be convert to and int or a float

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What's the easiest test to check if a varchar(500) column can be turned into a float or an interger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you  use parse int .  And there is non numeric in the string so the output is non.  Check this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To test it   you have to check every single character in the varchar.  There are many ways. Like loops or case statements.  After the testing use cast and convert function.

I guess the shortest way and less memory use is a parse int . Don't be in a vague. It's also loop system.